# Do the laws of geometric optics only apply to linear media?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, geometric-optics

Do the laws of geometric optics,

1. the incident, reflected and transmitted rays lie on the same plane;
2. $\theta_r = \theta_i$;
3. $n_i \sin\theta_i = n_t \sin\theta_t$ (Snell's law),

apply only when dealing with linear media? By a linear medium I mean one in which the polarization and magnetization are proportional to the electric field and auxiliary magnetic field respectively:

\begin{equation}
\bf{P} = \chi_e \varepsilon_0 \bf{E} \;\;\; \textrm{and} \;\;\; \bf{M} = \chi_m \bf{H}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Would you consider that those laws hold if, say, the beam 'dissolves' into two beams of different colors that go in different directions? What about a situation where the refractive index depends on the intensity but everything else stays the same?

Comment: I only ask that such laws apply in the same way that they apply to linear media. It would be constructive to outline in the answer how such laws apply to linear media.

Comment: You've implicitly assumed an isotropic medium as well as a linear medium.  Moreover, the medium is a dielectric; otherwise you'll have to consider a complex index of refraction

Comment: I'm not sure if this is too large an edit for me to suggest, but it may help to change your susceptibilities to be (a) linear operators (matrices/tensors) and (b) functions of spatial position. Because it sounds like you're looking for effects caused by making them more complicated maps than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if by "linear medium" you mean "linear isotropic medium" (which is implicit in the definition you gave).

For a linear *an*isotropic medium (also called "birefringent"), like calcite, your law 1 is false (the transmitted beam can bend out of the plane of the incident and reflected beams) and your law 3 is either false or meaningless (you can have $\theta_i=0$ but $\theta_t \neq 0$, cf. [birefringent beam displacers](https://www.altechna.com/product_details.php?id=1240), but there isn't really a meaningful value for $n_t$).

Here's a depiction of birefringent materials' blatant disregard for Snell's law: A normal incident beam tilting off-normal within the material:

[image: Picture of beam splitting by birefringent material]

Your law 2 is universally valid, if you define "the reflected beam" in the normal sense. It's almost tautological ... You *can* get beams at other angles. A reflected second-harmonic beam will go at a different angle. If the medium diffracts the light for whatever reason (e.g. the medium is made of atoms and the "light" is X-rays), the diffracted beams have other angles.

Comment: So your answer to the question is then "yes, if you mean linear isotropic medium"? Maybe you should explicitly state your final answer in relation to everything else you discuss?

Comment: Transverse walkoff, the phenomenon described here, can actually be derived from Fermat's principle (http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0963-9659/7/6/018). So really, I think geometrical optics works just fine for birefringent media; it includes more than what's described by the simplified form of Snell's law for isotropic media.

Comment: @ostrichCamel - thanks for the link! I agree on all counts. The thing OP calls "the laws of geometric optics" is not what I would call "the laws of geometric optics".